# What is Glew, Glut and glfw3? Which ones are deprecated in Opengl 3/4

Tags: c++, opengl

I have been reading online about how OpenGl 3 and 4 differ greatly from the previous versions.

Some tutorials ask to:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
```

Others will have:

```
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
```

What is `Glew`, `Glut` and `glfw3`? Which ones are deprecated and which ones are used in modern opengl?

Comment: I don't understand why moderator closed this question. This is the first ting that new OpenGl contributor asks when starts to learn it. It's quite an important question, and it is "as is", and doesn't need to be more focused.

Comment: OpenGL is already developed by the GPU manufacturers, saved as binary file in the graphics drive. You can use it without any additional libraries. However, this would be complicated, especially for unexperienced developers. For simplification, you can use any opengl loader library (`FreeGlut, Glad, Glew, GLUT`) + for windowing can use `GLFW`. GLUT is often not recommended, and `FreeGLUT` and `GLEW` are widely used. You can use `microsoft vcpkg` to install these libraries.

Answer (score 19):

GLEW (or OpenGL Extension Wrangler) is pretty much a loader, that helps you to manage OpenGl in an "easy" way. In general, functions of the OpenGL library are already on your computer, contained in binary form (.dll) inside your graphics drivers, and GLEW is a *portal* between you and OpenGl that *already lives there*. It provides the functionality of OpenGL in such a way, that is convenient for you to use. That's what GLEW developers mean by "load a pointer to function" - to access a graphics driver of your computer and load specific functions from it so that you can use them in your C++ code.

**Note**: You can actually do what GLEW does by yourself, as t.niese pointed out in the comment section, but that's quite a challenge for a beginner, and therefore it's more convenient to use GLEW.

GLFW (or Graphics Library Framework) on the other hand is a library that helps you to manage such things as window, its size, params, basic input and events-stuff. GLEW needs a window and a valid OpenGL context to be setup, and that's exactly where GLFW comes in handy.

What is also interesting that these libraries were made not just to make your developing life easier, but also your deployment faster. GLEW and GLFW are kind of cross-platform so you don't have to write different versions of the same application on different platforms.

As practice shows, GLEW/GLAD + GLFW is a common use for modern computer graphics based on OpenGL. You *could*, however, choose other libraries for a reason, based on what you need. But the general approach is to use these, because they support the latest versions of OpenGL, and always get updated.

If you are new to OpenGL and want to learn its basics, you should check this [youtube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlrATfBNZ98foTJPJ_Ev03o2oq3-GGOS2). There is a simple and quite fast OpenGL tutorial, and there are things that you should definitely know as a developer. Have a nice time!

---

**EDIT**

GLUT and GLFW are basically the same, but what you need to know is that the original GLUT has been unsupported for 20 years, and there is a free open-source alternative for it called freeglut. So, I guess that is what you mean by "deprecated" :)

Comment: `[...]GLFW … can't do much without GLEW (or GLAD, as an alternative) these days, because all you really can use from it to draw something are old methods from OpenGl[...]` is misleading. GLFW purpose is to manage OpenGL contexts and basics of window-, keyboard-, event-handling. It does not do automatic extension loading,  so without a loader like glad, you can only use what the system provides on its own (which could also be the current version). But you can load extensions/functions manually using GLFW, so you indeed could use modern OpenGL using only GLFW.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!