# Compiler flags for C++ using OpenGL, GLUT, GLEW

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, compiler-flags, linker-flags

When I am compiling simple examples it works with the following compiler instructions, but I don't understand them in detail:

```
clang -o name name.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lglfw -lGLEW -framework OpenGL
```

I understand the -o flag for the executable file and also the -L flag which clarifies where the compiler should search for libraries to use.

But when it comes to the -lglfw or -lGLEW flags I have no idea what they do. Same for the -framework flag, but there I have an idea what it does.

Also what is the difference between OpenGL, GLEW and GLUT?

Comment: As you say `-L.....` is where to look for libraries. `-l.....` is the library to look for.  `-framework` no idea.

Comment: Maybe the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#linker-flags) will help? Some of the arguments aren't documented but are just copied from [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options)

Comment: _"... Also what is the difference between OpenGL, GLEW and GLUT? ..."_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61671010/what-is-glew-glut-and-glfw3-which-ones-are-deprecated-in-opengl-3-4

Comment: If you're using another library (which also requires their own compiler flags), you can use the `pkg-config` application. Just typing `pkg-config --list-all` shows all libraries available. Using `pkg-config <libname> --cflags --libs` on terminal, it prints all compiler flags needed to compile your application using that library.